# How to implement Google's First Click Free on rails

Tags: google-search

if I click the url in the google search it should go to that page without login and after that for any action it should ask for login.... How to do it??

Comment: please add some more details to your question so that it can be clear enough for all to answer. i could not get what exactly are you asking

Answer (score 0):

A basic solution would be to use a flag in a session cookie:

- the first time a user requests a page from your site, the flag is not set: you set the flag in the session cookie, and display the page.
- the next time, if the flag is set and the user is not logged in: redirect user to the login page.

Of course, the user can remove their cookies on each request to browse your site without being logged in.

Comment: Actually i am using  "filter_access_to :all" for all controller. How to do that?